# Regular expressions C#

Tags: c#, regex

Can anybody tell me how to write regular exp for this string.

TRY MOVIE YES [Bat2man WIN]

(I tried backslash with [ but does not work)

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? What is expected result? You can write any regular expression for this string.

Comment: -1 Why does this need a regular expression?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to extract from that string?

Comment: `@"TRY MOVIE YES \[Bat2man WIN\]"`

Comment: It's very unclear what is being asked or what the desired answer is. There's no indication of what has been tried. Please give us more to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you escape brackets wrong:

Try this:

```
string regexTemplate = @"TRY MOVIE YES \[Bat2man WIN\]";
```

or

```
string regexTemplate = "TRY MOVIE YES \\[Bat2man WIN\\]";
```